# Что такое слоговой согласный звук?

Tags: морфология, недопустимая-метка

Например, в словах ***октябрь*** и ***джентльмен***?

Другие примеры, пожалуйста! С разъяснениями!

---

По получении ответов; рассказываю, как меня занесло в проблему:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нет, ну скажите, чудо какое этот русский язык! )))

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста автора и название книги?

Comment: Катя, за пять с лишним лет я, конечно же, забыла. Нужно ввести вручную цитату в поиск и кликнуть Гугл-Кгиги.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Галина, что это Вас занесло в такие дебри?

Слоговой согласный проявляется только в беглой разговорной речи, когда гласный редуцируется и исчезает, а звучность переходит на сонорный согласный и этот согласный становится слоговым, при разборе слог засчитывается: сделала[з'д'э-л-лъ], полочка, Ивановна[ива-н-нъ], колокольчик [ка-л-кол'-чик]

Гораздо реже встречаются в потоке речи слогообразующие шумные звуки: тссс!

о-ктя-брь-слоговой дрожащий Р , игнорирование этого факта ведёт к неверному произношению [акт'абыр']

джен-тль-мен - слоговой сонорный Л, а кто его не видит, читает [джэн-тэл'-м'эн]

Comment: Людмила, а персонально для тупых. Чем неправильна передача слогообразующего согласного (не только сонорного) через [ър]/[ыр], [ъл]/[ыл] и т. п.? Меня очень поэты всегда в подобных случаях убеждают. *Ревет сынок. Побит за двойку с плюсом. // Жена на локоны взяла последний рубль. // Супруг, убитый лавочкой и флюсом, // Подсчитывает месячную убыль.*

Comment: Люся, меня просто очень удивило само явление, сам факт наличия такого чуда, как слоговой согласный. Я им, конечно, активно пользовалась (рубыль - убыль), но имени не знала. Чем, вестимо, оказалась удручена и вся, как результат, извопросилась.

Comment: *просто очень удивило само явление, сам факт наличия такого чуда, как слоговой согласный*  - Есть многое в природе, друг Горацио, Что и не снилось нашим мудрецам. Это Вам Серж хорошо расскажет, сколько слогов в имени-фамилии **Мкртч Мкртчян**. )))

Comment: Ну знаете, behemothus, как это чем неправильна? Это разговорный стиль, не норма. А поэты, они для ритма  и не то ещё придумают, у них и гласные бывают неслогообразующими, они не могут убедить в правильности чего-то, у них всё субъективно.

Answer (score 1):

Напряженный согласный звук, который так же, как и сам сонорный в слоге, может образовывать вершину слога. Например, в русском междометии кс-кс-кс три слога, хотя все звуки глухие, слоговой здесь – звук [с]. Глухой щелевой согласный выступает слоговым в возгласе отпугивания птиц: -кш (слоговой звук [ш]).

Словарь лингвистических терминов: Изд. 5-е, испр-е и дополн. — Назрань: Изд-во "Пилигрим". Т.В. Жеребило. 2010.

В словах ***октябрь и джентльмен*** слоговым согласным выступает сонарный, который часто выпадает при произношении. Также см. [Слоговые и неслоговые звуки.](http://www.textologia.ru/russkiy/fonetika-fonologia/slog/slogoobrazuyuschie-i-neslogoobrazuyuschie-zvuki-v-russkom-yazike/4004/?q=463&n=4004)

Comment: Серж, спасибо за ответ, но Ваша ссылка привела меня в английский, а вопрос о русском... На примерах двух слов - октябрь и джентльмен. Как в них согласный может дать дополнительный слог? Какой именно сонарный?

Comment: И я бы сказала, что в примерах с бесслоговыми "кс" и "кш" слог образует начальное "к": кыс-кыс (не кис-кис) и кыш (отседова). Но могу и ошибаться! )))

Comment: Обнаружила русский разбор полетов по той же ссылке; "наш" случай - это [т'и атр] и [т'и атэр]. И ничего сонорного!

Comment: Серж, Ваша ссылка у меня перестала работать; тот же текст найден на сайте http://refwin.ru/1620109097.html Искала слово "сонарный" - у Вас опечатка, исправьте на "сонорный" - последний абзац.

Comment: Галина, странно, но в моей ссылке речь идет о русском языке. В слогах кс-кс-кс - ы не произносится. Хотя некоторые могут произнести через ы. Хотя в ваших примерах речь идет о сонорных согласных.Попробуйте произнести с ы и без. Вы почувствуете разницу. В слове ''октябрьский''[акт'апск'ии] (см.там же) сонорный выпадает.

Comment: Галина, в вашей ссылке тот же самый текст, что и в моей.

Comment: Просто Ваша громадная ссылка, Серж, не помещается в адресную строку (даже не пойму, откуда Вы её скопировали), и выходит ошибка 404.

Comment: Артем, в том-то дело, у меня открывается. Сейчас попробую Галиноной ссылкой заменить.текст один и тот же.

Comment: Серж, это очень сомнительный сайт... Фонетическая транскрипция слова октябрьский: [акт'`абр'ск'ий']. По кыс, кыш, тыс я задала вопрос, - посмотрим, что люди думают.

Comment: Галина, в книге Русский язык. Фонетика и фонология. Орфоэпия. Графика и орфография. - М., 2003 г.Андрейченко Л.Н., также говорится, что в разговорной речи возможны согласные слоговые звуки. Там же приводятся те же примеры: кс, тс.

Comment: У меня по ссылке - какие-то картинки из учебника по бухгалтерии.

Comment: "даже не пойму, откуда Вы её скопировали)" - из яндекса, откуда ж еще.  А после исправления - ссылка на тот же сомнительный рисурс с картинками по бухгалтерии.

Comment: Странно, но у меня нормально открывается. Да, скопировал из Яндекса. Но потом исправил на ссылку Галины.

Comment: Так открываться-то он открывается. И даже текст частично адекватный.  Но картинки (якобы со схемами) - из какого-то параллельного мира. Это может быть глюк DNS, хотя я с подобным раньше не сталкивался. Если не отпустит до вечера - Сделаю скрин, выложу.

Comment: Это я про старый источник. Сейчас, на текстологии (http://www.textologia.ru/)  все ОК. А то я вас запутаю.

Comment: Я понял, что Вы про старый источник. Поэтому заменил ссылку на Текстологию. Материал один и тот же.

Answer (score 1):

Только чтобы воспроизвести красивый вид, повторю пример, который для Людмилы давал.

*Ревет сынок. Побит за двойку с плюсом.

Жена на локоны взяла последний **рубль**.

Супруг, убитый лавочкой и флюсом,

Подсчитывает месячную **убыль**.*

(Саша Черный).

Еще пример - "жизнь". Его не все принимают, но там Н, который можно считать "полуслоговым", что ли. В том смысле, что [жызън'] - не будет считаться орфоэпической ошибкой.

Comment: Бегемотик, спасибо! )))

Comment: Что такое... Пропал комметарий. Повторюсь.

Comment: Галина, да не за что. Только у нас тут более приняты менее фамильярные обращения. Я на Бегемотика не обижаюсь нисколько, не знаю, как Людмила, но вот для гостей это точно дополнительные проблемы в поиске источника и адресата.

Comment: А вот этого я Вам уже не смогу позволить.

Comment: Э-э-э... Оживлянса?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31899/discussion-between-behemothus-and-galina-avanesova).

Comment: И еще "Жеманства и чопорности". Мы аниматора в дом отдыха не заказывали.

Answer (score 1):

Да, с поэтами тяжко. Вот пример - соседние строки в стихе:

Журавль — со злом напрасная война,
журавль — беспокойная свобода.

У первого слова "журавль" два слога, а у второго - три. "Я так слышу" - и хоть убей.

Comment: Ну да.  И я так слышу. )))