# Анаптиксис - есть общепринятые обозначения?

Tags: фонетика, орфоэпия

Анаптиксис – добавление звука к слогообразующему сонантному согласному звуку.
В современном русском литературном языке слогообразующими звуками являются исключительно гласные.

К моему вящему удивлению, поэтическая речь к нормативно-литературной не относится - "непишущиеся" гласные подразумеваются в стихах не так уж и редко. Например:

Жизнь — отражение лунного лика в воде,
Сфера, чей цент(о)р повсюду, окружность нигде. 
(К. Бальмонт)

Существует ли более или менее общепринятое (в лингвистических кругах) обозначение анаптиксиса на письме? Апостроф между согласными вставлять, что ли?

Comment: Не понимаю смысла. Зачем на письме его обозначать?

Comment: Спасибо, что обратили внимание на мой вопрос - когда-то Вы помогали мне разобраться с правилом «запрета переакцентуации» в поэтической речи.

Comment: Обозначать нужно факт дополнительного слога для получения верной ритмической картинки поэтической строки. Можно, конечно, просто вставлять "непишущуюся гласную", но тогда будет орфографическая ошибка. А просто в словарь вставить не годится - один и тот же поэт в разных ситуациях то слышит эту гласную, то не слышит.

Comment: Тогда это не "на письме" а при кодировании в каких-то собственных целях, транскрипции, что ли. А там есть правила МФА, например, но можете и свои собственные придумать, можете **шва** использовать. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C6%8F_%D0%B8_%C6%8E#.C6.8F

Comment: Увы, именно что "на письме", а вернее - при вводе текста стиха в редакторе моей программы.   Закавыка тут ещё в том, что я понятия не имею, как слышится та "непишущаяся гласная" конкретному поэту. Что же, пускай либо пишут ту гласную, что слышат, и мирятся с орфографической ошибкой, либо ставят апостроф после согласной. Хотя в последнем варианте проблема просто смягчается: проверку ритма и орфографии такое обозначение в моей программе пройдёт, а вот при подборе рифмы к этому слову возникнут сложности.    Спасибо за подсказку.

Comment: Ну так если это ввод исключительно в вашу программу, зачем Вам искать какие-то аналогии? Но если уж так надо, возьмите Шва или апостроф или вообще любой символ.

Comment: Я крайне не люблю изобретать велосипед, если есть шанс позаимствовать готовый. Но придётся...

Comment: А что, уже есть велосипед, похожий на вашу программу?

Comment: Обижаете! Моя программа - это целая куча велосипедов! И на парочку копирайты у меня  ;) Словари рифм есть, а в остальном пока что я в гордом одиночестве.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял Ваш вопрос... Для программы следует вставлять все гласные. Апостроф она вряд ли воспримет как слог.

Comment: Этот вариант уже озвучивался. Проблема в том что (1) я не знаю, какую гласную там слышит поэт (2) добавление лишней гласной вызывает орфографическую ошибку, а по поводу апострофа я могу объяснить программе, что для анализа орфографии апостроф следует игнорировать, для анализа ритмичности - считать слогообразующим (как гласная). Да и читатель-человек поймёт, что применение апострофа в русском слове, не подпадающее ни под какие существующие нормы - это произношение.

Answer (score 0):

Общепринятыми будут понятия *слогообразующие согласные* и *неслогообразующие гласные*, или просто *слоговые/неслоговые*.

См. [мой вопрос и ответ Людмилы](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/419626/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA).

Comment: Понятия - это хорошо. Но меня интересует - как бы эту слогообразующую (по мнению конкретного поэта, но не всех носителей языка) согласную обозначить, и так, чтобы увидевший это обозначение понял: здесь произносится что-то похожее на гласную, но её не пишут.

Comment: Ой, у Сельвинского, кажись, такие эксперименты были... Апостроф - это выход.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию.

Comment: А где аплодисменты в виде кликанья по верхнему треугольничку и по галочке-загогулинке под нижним?! О_о